# Is there a way to install a Pitney Bowes LPS-1 printer on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

I have been trying without success to get Windows 10 to recognize a Pitney Bowes LPS-1 label printer on a USB port. USBView gives me this information:

```
[Port6]  :  USB Printing Support

Is Port User Connectable:         yes
Is Port Debug Capable:            no
Companion Port Number:            0
Companion Hub Symbolic Link Name: 
Protocols Supported:
 USB 1.1:                         yes
 USB 2.0:                         yes
 USB 3.0:                         no

Device Power State:               PowerDeviceD0

       ---===>Device Information<===---
English product name: "LPS-1"

ConnectionStatus:                  
Current Config Value:              0x01  -> Device Bus Speed: Full (is not SuperSpeed or higher capable)
Device Address:                    0x04
Open Pipes:                           2

          ===>Device Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x12
bDescriptorType:                   0x01
bcdUSB:                          0x0110
bDeviceClass:                      0x00  -> This is an Interface Class Defined Device
bDeviceSubClass:                   0x00
bDeviceProtocol:                   0x00
bMaxPacketSize0:                   0x08 = (8) Bytes
idVendor:                        0x04F9 = Brother Industries, Ltd.
idProduct:                       0x2050
bcdDevice:                       0x0100
iManufacturer:                     0x01
     English (United States)  "Pitney Bowes "
iProduct:                          0x02
     English (United States)  "LPS-1"
iSerialNumber:                     0x03
     English (United States)  "F5G114971"
bNumConfigurations:                0x01

          ---===>Open Pipes<===---

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0010 = 0x10 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x02  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 2
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

       ---===>Full Configuration Descriptor<===---

          ===>Configuration Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x02
wTotalLength:                    0x0020  -> Validated
bNumInterfaces:                    0x01
bConfigurationValue:               0x01
iConfiguration:                    0x00
bmAttributes:                      0xC0  -> Self Powered
MaxPower:                          0x00 =   0 mA

          ===>Interface Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x09
bDescriptorType:                   0x04
bInterfaceNumber:                  0x00
bAlternateSetting:                 0x00
bNumEndpoints:                     0x02
bInterfaceClass:                   0x07  -> This is a Printer USB Device Interface Class
bInterfaceSubClass:                0x01
bInterfaceProtocol:                0x02
iInterface:                        0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x81  -> Direction: IN - EndpointID: 1
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0010 = 0x10 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00

          ===>Endpoint Descriptor<===
bLength:                           0x07
bDescriptorType:                   0x05
bEndpointAddress:                  0x02  -> Direction: OUT - EndpointID: 2
bmAttributes:                      0x02  -> Bulk Transfer Type
wMaxPacketSize:                  0x0040 = 0x40 bytes
bInterval:                         0x00
```

I do not understand why Windows refuses to see it as a printer on a USB port. Has anyone successfully installed this printer, even as its OEM model, the Brother QL-500? (The Brother driver installer does not see the printer.)

Comment: You would need a USB device driver for the specific USB vendor ID and product ID.

Comment: I would try this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/lps-1-pitney-bowes-label-printer-not-working/07aa5d7b-0175-4454-abbf-7989a46e6214 But keep in mind that may no longer work, even the "hack" of using the other model's driver/software because it's sadly too old and manufacturers often drop support for legacy hardware. They'll happily sell a brand new fully Windows 10 compatible one though.

Comment: @ChanganAuto i already saw that, it's too old and useless. It would help if I could find the original drive package for Windows XP, but PB has made sure it is no longer available. Useless company, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This printer can be used under Windows 10 as a Brother QL-500 but you have to get around the base installer, which blocks the install if it doesn't see a printer that identifies itself as a Brother printer.

Once you download the QL-500/550 driver installer from the Brother web site, it will create a folder called "qd500w550bus". Navigate to the folder, then down to the ..\x64\QL500 folder. There, run the "dsetupn.exe" file and complete the driver install. You will need to restart the machine. Note that in my case I had to change the port on the printer entry in settings to use USB001, a virtual USB port. I have no idea why that is the case. The driver will install itself to print to file by default.

You can now use the LPS-1 as a label printer, but you have to make sure that printer driver is setup to use the label size you have loaded into the printer. Use the printer properties to change that as necessary. Note that to use some Brother-style label cartridges you may have to remove tabs at the bottom to get it to fully drop into the printer.